# Missing value while parsing webpage with BeautifulSoup 4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, missing-data

As a practice assignment I am trying to parse [this search results page](http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=android) from Amazon using BeautifulSoup library.

Here's my code.

```
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


SourceURL = "http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=android"
ResultsPage = urlopen(SourceURL )
Soup = BeautifulSoup(ResultsPage)


print "<SearchResults>"

for SearchResult in Soup.findAll('li', attrs={'class': 's-result-item celwidget'}):
    #Read Result Title
    Title = SearchResult.find("h2", {"class": "a-size-medium a-color-null s-inline s-access-title a-text-normal"})

    ResultTag = "\t<Result><![CDATA["
    if Title is not None:
        ResultTag += Title.text

    ResultTag += "]]></Result>"
    print ResultTag

print "</SearchResults>"
```

The output displayed is as below

```
<SearchResults>
    <Result><![CDATA[Micromax Bolt S301 (Black, No charger, No earphone inbox)]]></Result>
    <Result><![CDATA[Android Application Development (with Kitkat Support), Black Book]]></Result>
    <Result><![CDATA[ZTE Blade Buzz White V815W]]></Result>
    <Result><![CDATA[Android:  App Development & Programming Guide: Learn In A Day! (Android, Rails, Ruby Programming, App Development...]]></Result>
    <Result><![CDATA[]]></Result>
    <Result><![CDATA[Karbonn Titanium S21 (Grey)]]></Result>
    <Result><![CDATA[Head First Android Development]]></Result>
    <Result><![CDATA[Micromax Canvas A1 Android One (White, 8GB)]]></Result>
    <Result><![CDATA[Professional Android 4 Application Development (Wrox)]]></Result>
    <Result><![CDATA[OnePlus X (Onyx) - Invite Only]]></Result>
    <Result><![CDATA[Lenovo Vibe S1 (4G, White)]]></Result>
    <Result><![CDATA[Micromax Bolt D320 (Black, 4GB)]]></Result>
    <Result><![CDATA[2 in 1 Capacitive Stylus Pen With Black Ball Pen for Android Touch Sceen Mobile Phones and Tablets All iPads and...]]></Result>
    <Result><![CDATA[Moto E 2nd Generation XT1506 (3G, Black)]]></Result>
    <Result><![CDATA[Android: App Development & Programming Guide: Learn In A Day!]]></Result>
    <Result><![CDATA[Lenovo Vibe S1 (4G, Dark Blue)]]></Result>
</SearchResults>
```

If you notice, fifth result is missing from the output for some reason, while it prints all other rows with same code. Essentially, SearchResult.find() method is returning NULL value only for one record.

Can you please let me know if I am missing something?

Thanks,
Nikhil

Comment: I just ran `l=document.querySelectorAll('li.s-result-item.celwidget'); for ( var i = 0; i < l.length; i++ ) {console.log(l.item(i));   k=l[i].querySelectorAll('h2.a-size-medium.a-color-null.s-inline.s-access-title.a-text-normal'); for ( var j = 0; j < k.length; j++ ) console.log("  ", k[j].innerHTML);   }` on that page and it does list everything correctly, so at least there's nothing weird with the HTML markup. Maybe you could add an `else` to the if, appending [the path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969474/beautifulsoup-extract-xpath-or-css-path-of-node) for the li to the result?

Answer (score 0):

if you look at your link http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=android, the 5th `li` element matches your criteria for class name `s-result-item celwidget` , which actually is `Customers shopped for android in` and does not completely match your second criteria of `a-size-medium a-color-null s-inline s-access-title a-text-normal`, which is causing `Title` to be set to none.

You can probably update your condition to below to print desired output.

```
if Title is not None:
    ResultTag = "\t<Result><![CDATA["
    ResultTag += Title.text
    ResultTag += "]]></Result>"
    print ResultTag
```

Comment: Thanks @akotian. Can you please explain "which actually is Customers shopped for android in and does not completely match your second criteria of a-size-medium a-color-null s-inline s-access-title a-text-normal".  Just curious as other results - which were probably produced by the same code at server side - are matching the same criteria.

Comment: If you open up the link you posted in a browser window, and [open javascript console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/console-ui?hl=en#opening-the-console), you can see what I am talking about.
`document.getElementsByClassName('s-result-item')[3].getElementsByClassName("a-size-medium a-color-null s-inline s-access-title a-text-normal")` will return an element
`document.getElementsByClassName('s-result-item')[4].getElementsByClassName("a-size-medium a-color-null s-inline s-access-title a-text-normal")` returns empty. Because thats how the html is set up.