# Is there a way to find the exact path of an element in the requests module in Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Is there a way to select the exact "div" in a source of a Beautiful Soup object? For example, let's say we have soup like this:

```
    <div class="dialog-shadow" id="popupMenu1" onblur="hidePopup();" onmouseout="closePopup = contextMenuInputHasFocus() ? null : setTimeout('hidePopup()',500);" onmouseover="if(closePopup!=null){clearTimeout(closePopup);closePopup=null}"></div>
<div id="popupMenu2" onblur="hidePopup();" onmouseout="closePopup = contextMenuInputHasFocus() ? null : setTimeout('hidePopup()',500);" onmouseover="if(closePopup!=null){clearTimeout(closePopup);closePopup=null}"></div>
<div class="shadow" id="popupMenu3" onblur="hidePopup3();hidePopup();" onmouseout="closePopup = setTimeout('hidePopup();', 500); closePopup3 = setTimeout('hidePopup3()',500);" onmouseover="if(closePopup!=null){clearTimeout(closePopup);closePopup=null};if(closePopup3!=null){clearTimeout(closePopup3);closePopup3=null};"></div>
<div id="container">
<div class="background-menu-dark shadow" id="navHolder">
<span class="customBranding" id="logo" onclick="loadView(V_SUMMARY);" title="Özet Görünümü"><img height="40" src="Branding/SmallBanner.jpg?ts=20140403111116"/></span>
<div id="navigation">
<ul id="navigationLargeWidth">
<li id="mainInboxLink">
```

And I want to find the third div whose class is "shadow" in this piece of soup. But when I do something like this, it returns `None`:

```
soup.find('div',attrs={"class":"shadow"})
```

I know that it should be something like "ABC-->BC-->C" If i want to find C in the soup, but is there a way that I can find C just by knowing its unique class or ID?

**(soup.select("div:nth-of-type(3))) is not what I'm looking for)**

Comment: I see only 2 divs with that class. Is there an url we can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see only 2 divs with that class. However, the reason your nth-of-type could be failing is due to you not including the class. Unless there is some reason (you haven't given) as to why `nth-of-type` itself is not acceptable.

```
div.shadow:nth-of-type(3)
```

without proper html to test with I cannot be sure of index or whether content is dynamically loaded (if from webpage)

If you are trying to dynamically construct the path then something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969474/beautifulsoup-extract-xpath-or-css-path-of-node)?

For a div with a unique class

```
select_one('div.shadow')
```

Comment: It's about the mail page of my university. I am going to take the unread mails so unfortunately It doesn't matter whether you  see the url.But I couldn't understand that part ""div.shadow:nth-of-type(3)"". Let me make it clear. I want to find a div (It's not important which one it is now) and this div has a uniqie class. Forget about the shadow one. Can I select it just by doing the thing I have shown above? Thanks in advance

Comment: you can do select_one('div.shadow')   if it returns None then it is possible the element is dynamically added. Unsure how bs4 deals with iframe/frame - but worth checking if there is a parent iframe/frame.